# What is the difference between Animation.AnimationListener and Animator.AnimatorListener?

Tags: android, android-animation, semantics

All I can see is that one Listener comes from `Animation` and the other comes from `Animator`, with the latter (added in API 11) being a more recent addition to the Android API. Which should be used in which situation, and are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the two are:

`Animator.AnimatorListener`
`Animation.AnimationListener`

Anything under the `Animation` package is used for the old (pre-Honeycomb) View animations. For example, `AlphaAnimation` or `ScaleAnimation` used with `View.startAnimation()` and `View.clearAnimation()`.

The `Animator` classes are the new animation framework introduced in Honeycomb, such as `ObjectAnimator` and `ValueAnimator`.

If you're supporting only API 11+, I'd highly recommend using `Animator` over `Animation`. Much easier to work with.

The difference of the listeners is that the `Animation.AnimationListener` is the type required by `Animation` subclasses, and the `Animator.AnimatorListener` interface is required by `Animator` subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

they don't extend or impelments the same class or interface so they are not interchangeble.

[`Animation.AnimatorListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) is used with the old [`android.view.animation.*`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) animation framework, the other one ([`Animator.AnimationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html)) with the new one [`android.animation.*`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html)